# App Engine: different results for same objectify query

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, objectify

I am developing a small backend with app engine. Now I get some weird behaviour after saving an entity multiple times with different values.
My code to load entities is the same for all entities - each entity gets a changeId so I can transfer only changed entities to the clients:

```
public class VersionableRecordHelper<T extends VersionableRecord> {

final Class<T> clazz;

public VersionableRecordHelper(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

Query<T> load() {
    return ofy().load().type(clazz);
}

List<T> loadOrdered() {
    return load().order("changeId").list();
}

public List<T> loadOrdered(Long since) {
    return since == null ? loadOrdered() : load().filter("changeId >", since).order("changeId").list();
}

}
```

The clients then can query all objects of a class by providing a `since` value. For example:

```
private final VersionableRecordHelper<Cat> helper
    = new VersionableRecordHelper<>(Cat.class);

// actually an @ApiMethod, simplified here
public List<Cat> getCats(Long since) {
    return helper.loadOrdered(since);
}
```

My Cat entity looks like the following:

```
@Entity
@Cache
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
public class Cat extends VersionableRecord {
    // some fields, getters, setters
}

public class VersionableRecord {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Index
    private Long changeId;

    // getters, setters and more
}
```

Now, if I do the same REST request with `since == 4`, I get **completely different results** - sometimes with changeId == 5, **but also with 2, 3 or 4 - which should not even be possible**!

I am completely lost here. This is what I checked yet:

- I did not change the records during the test. In fact, I completely left the records alone for more than 90 minutes.
- I checked that only one app engine instance was running.
- I tried to flush the memcache - but the same 2 ObjectifyCache keys keep hanging around.
- The memcache service level is 'Shared'.
- I checked that the value of `since`is not null by any chance. So the code definitely gets executed.
- Currently I am using objectify version 5.0.3. From my build.gradle: `compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'`
- I also made sure the entity has the correct changeId in the datastore by checking https://console.developers.google.com/project/project-id/datastore/query?authuser=0

Does anyone have a helpful idea? I also checked for different type of entities - the same behaviour.

Comment: Maybe I am just stating the obvious. But are you sure that when you do a REST call your code is actually getting hit and there is no http cache in the middle returning you a wrong previous value)?

Comment: Hey @Claudio - no, it's definitely not. I can call it with the `curl` utility and still get different results. Browser, curl, iOS app - still the same.

Comment: I found out that if I *manually shutdown* my instance and let a new one start automatically that everything works as expected. But that can't be the solution. ;)

Comment: Have you tried to disable the Objectify caches (there are two cache levels if I remember correctly) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess, this is related to FAQ #3:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Strange_things_are_showing_up_in_my_session_cache!_(or_missing_f

or, when googlecode dies, the third one down:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

You need to have the `ObjectifyFilter` installed otherwise you will bleed session data into subsequent requests. Upgrade to a more recent version of Objectify; it will give you a more explicit error (at the cost of complicating test and remote api usage, but that's a different story).

If this isn't your issue, you need to describe your exact code in more detail.

Comment: This is the correct answer - I missed to add the ObjectifyFilter to web.xml. Thank you for helping! :)   I now see that the setup document clearly states to enable ObjectifyFilter on https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup - but I believe this could have been designed in a better, more user-friendly and fail-safe way.

Comment: Very recent versions of Objectify make this an explicit error (at the cost of making certain other usages of Objectify slightly more complicated). Please upgrade :)

Comment: Ok, I upgraded to Objectify 5.1.5! Hopefully the new version works as expected. Thanks again for your help! :)